# Javascript String Type Conversion issue in Vs code

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?
i have just started learning Javascript and currently on type conversions.

```js
let main = true;
console.log(typeof main);

main = string(main);
console.log(typeof main);
```

the first two lines of code correctly shows type of main as boolean but when in the thrid line i convert it to string , it doesn't show anything.

Using VS CODE Editor.

Comment: I thing its typo. use [`String()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp) instead of `string()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct class is, `String` not `string`

Replace

```
main = string(main)
```

with

```
 main = String(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toString for cast:

```js
let main=true;
alert(typeof main);

main = main.toString();
alert(typeof main);
```